# How to provide JSON request body for GET method in Karate API

Tags: karate

How to provide request body for GET method using Karate API.

When trying to provide Request body for Get method in Karate API, it doesnt take the request and throws 500 status code.

Comment: You really need to provide some sort of code...

Comment: Given url SERVICEURL                                                                                 And header Accept = 'application/json'                                                                   
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'                                                                 
And request {name:'ddd'}                                                                                                                               
When method GET

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
using the request body within a GET request to change the semantics of the request is highly discouraged.

It's debatable that Karate ignores the message body when using `method GET` and if you think there is a use case for that feature your free to file an [issue](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues).

Furthermore, the `500` status code you observe is returned by your system under test because of the missing message body and has nothing to do with karate.

EDIT: confirmed that [Karate 1.0](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide) will support a body along with a GET

Comment: yeah. anyone is free to open a feature request - but we'd expect a code contrib for this - I have a feeling this may not be supported by even the apache / jersey clients we use. worth nothing that this is the first time in 2 years that we got such a request

Comment: [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html) is widely used product that uses the message body in combination with GET request. 
So, there may be a use case to not ignore the message body.