# How do we test a GET call with POST body in its request using karate

Tags: karate

How do we test a GET call with POST body in its request using karate API.

When trying to provide Request body for Get method in Karate API, it doesn't take the request and throws 400 status code and says expected JSONArray and found Null

Answer (score 0):

A body for a `GET` is supported in the latest versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812032/143475

Else your question does not make sense, so please consider this not supported in Karate.

Comment: I am using the latest karate version mentioned in the docs and here is my request: Scenario:  Validate valid get response 

  * url  “url"
  * header Accept = "application/json"
  * header Content-Type = "application/json"

 * def requestbody = [“blah”]
  When request requestbody
  And header client_id = “xyz"
  And header client_secret = “abc"
  
  And method GET
  Then status 200 . Could you please let me know if there is something wrong with the request? The failure i get is expected type: JSONArray, found: Null

Comment: @Sun09 as I said, look for another tool please. or contribute code to karate. or prove that this is a bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue